# Is it true that linear relations between outer products remains unchanged under change of basis that are full column rank?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a set of outer products $\{ u_i v^T_i \}_i$. I want to show that they are linearly independent. i.e.:

$$ \sum^k_{i=1} \alpha_i u_i v^T_i = 0 \iff \alpha_i = 0$$

However, I only know for sure that a related set of outer products $\{ \hat u_i \hat v^T_i \}_i$ is linearly independent, i.e.:

$$ \sum^k_{i=1} \hat \alpha_i \hat u_i \hat v^T_i = 0 \iff \hat \alpha_i = 0$$

where $u_i = U \hat u_i $ under a change of basis according to the full column rank linear transformation imposed by $U$. Similarly for $v_i = V \hat v_i $ and V is full column rank.

Is it true that all the linear relationships between $\{ u_i v^T_i \}_i$ and $\{ \hat u_i \hat v^T_i \}_i$ is the same? In particular, is the independent one above hold? Its not clear to me how a change of basis (even if it's full rank) just doesn't destroy or change all the linear relationships.

Comment: Yes, it's true.  Long story short: you can factor out a $U$ and $U^T$ on each side.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom but that only works when its equal to zero..right? I was also interested in knowing if it preserved all linear relationships. Thnx btw! :)

Comment: That should always work

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$ 
\sum^k_{i=1} \alpha_i u_i v^T_i = 
\sum^k_{i=1} \alpha_i (U \hat u_i) (V \hat v_i)^T = 
\sum^k_{i=1} \alpha_i U \hat u_i \hat v_i^T V^T = 
U \left(\sum^k_{i=1} \alpha_i \hat u_i \hat v_i^T\right) V^T
$$
That should give you everything you're looking for.